# Update previous List<> Element

Tags: c#, list

Using a foreach loop I can update the 'current' element of the list.  I am trying to update the previous element using the int value but this doesn't work.  How do I properly access the previous item?

```
var myList = listPrelim.ToList(); 

int i = 0;
MyCustomClass previous = new MyCustomClass();

foreach (MyCustomClass current in myList)
{                
    current.IGNORE = true;  // works
    previous.IGNORE = false; // works
    previous = current;
    i++;
}
```

Update1:

```
accessing the previous.property works.
```

Comment: Why don't you simply access `previous.IGNORE`?

Comment: accessing previous.IGNORE doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't appear to work"  does not make a question.

Comment: If it somehow worked, the first iteration would access ` myList[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
var myList = listPrelim.ToList();    
MyCustomClass previous = null;

foreach (MyCustomClass current in myList)
{                
  current.IGNORE = true; 
  if(previous != null) 
    previous.IGNORE = false;
  previous = current;
}
```

The result of this code is a bit absurd, since you are just setting all elements' `IGNORE` to `false` except for the last, but I just assumed it'd be some example code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest assigning the current to a previous at the end of each "foreach loop"

so in int terms it would look like this: (*p.s. please excuse the pseudo code*)

```
int prev = 0
foreach (int cur in [1,10])
{
  //do something
  //more code
  //at the end
  prev = cur
}
```

so right at the beginning of each loop, prev will hold the previous int until it has been reassigned.

Hope this helps :p

Answer (score 0):

Try the **for** loop (myList[i], myList[i-1] are pointers).

```
        var myList = listPrelim.ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            myList[i].IGNORE = true;
            if (i-1>=0)
                myList[i - 1].IGNORE = false;

        }
```